# A bit of help using Google maps

Tags: google-maps, distance, route

I have 1000 or so points on a map, (I have GPS coordinates. I would like to use google maps to find the shortest distance using roads, between pairs of points. I would like to measure all pairs within a distance of 100km. Is this possible?

Comment: Using the [distance matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) this will be possible. Do you mean all pairs within 100km as the crow flies or as the car drives? Are you prepared to write some Javascript? Also, have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you may run against usage limits:

```
Users of the free API:
100 elements per query.
100 elements per 10 seconds.
2 500 elements per 24 hour period.
```

Read more at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#Limits